# Using c to create h file

Tags: c, header, cfile, hfile

I have a source file where a typedef struct is defined:

```
typedef struct {
    unsigned int seed;
} generator;

generator *create() {
    generator *g = (generator*)malloc(sizeof(generator));
    g->seed = time(0);     
    return g;
}

void set_seed(generator *g, unsigned int s) {
    g->seed = s;
}

unsigned int rand_int(generator *g) {
    return g->seed = (a * g->seed) % m;
}
```

I need to write header file, .h file. But I am keep getting

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_main", referenced from:
     implicit entry/start for main executable
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
```

To avoid this error, please help me with writing the .h file.

Comment: A linker error is not caused by a bad or missing header file.

Comment: well it complains that there is no main() in what you link...

Answer (score 0):

Add this code snippet to your code:

```
int main(void) {}
```

You a lacking the `main` function in your program.